# Too many Callbacks in Tweenmax js

Tags: javascript, gsap

Is there any better way to write this type of code in Tweenmax?

```
TweenMax.to("#second-scene .layer-one", 0.5, {delay:0.2, top:0, onComplete: function() { 

                    TweenMax.to("#second-scene .layer-two", 0.5, {top:0, onComplete: function() {

                        TweenMax.to("#second-scene .layer-three", 0.5, {left:0, onComplete: function() {

                            TweenMax.to("#second-scene .layer-four", 0.5, {left:0, onComplete: function() {

                                TweenMax.to("#second-scene .layer-five", 0.5, {left:0, onComplete: function() {

                                    TweenMax.to("#second-scene .layer-six", 0.5, {top:0} );

                                }} );
                            }} );
                        }} );
                    }} );
                }} );
```

And I would like to know if writing this way would affect performance.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [TimelineLite/Max](http://greensock.com/timelinelite):

```
var tl = new TimelineLite();

tl.to("#second-scene .layer-one", 0.5, {delay:0.2, top:0});
tl.to("#second-scene .layer-two", 0.5, {top:0});
//and so on
```

Timeline executes animations in sequence, so no need of callbacks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Staggered Animation method for similar tweening objects. Allows you to define an array of objects, time between each stagger,  callbacks etc.

```
var objects = [obj1, obj2, obj3];
TweenMax.staggerFromTo(objects, 3, {top:100}, {top:0}, 0);
```

[TweenMax.staggerFromTo()](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/staggerFromTo/)

Performance wise, I don't think it would be any different. Just makes for more readable and editable code.